# Finding Closest coordinates in sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm looking for a quick way (With a relative short query length) to find the rows with the closest x, y, coordinates in a database, and return the twenty closest. Closest as in the x-y coordinates are closest to the results.  The database looks like this.

```
-----------------
|Stuff  | x | y  |
------------------
|bob    |-21| 32 |
|Joe    |23 | 29 |
------------------
```

So, a search would be like x=19, y=32, and I would like twenty closest results, sorted by closeness. X-Y is a completely square grid.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

If this helps, I'm using MariaDB Version 10.3.27 on raspbian/debian

Comment: Please define "closest".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of measuring closest is to use Manhattan difference, the sum of the absolute value of the differences:

```
select t.*
from t
order by abs(x - @x) + abs(y - @y)
limit 20;
```

If you have a different distance metric, you would just plug that formula in.